# File Attachment control events in InfoPath 2010

Tags: development, attachments

Does anyone know of any kind of click events for the File Attachment Control in InfoPath 2010 forms? Here is a link to the control http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd958468(v=office.12).aspx.

What I am trying to do, is when a user clicks the control to download and save the attachment, I want to grab the base64 encoded string. Basically, I want to know if anyone has created any kind of events for the File Attachment Control. I am using these forms inside the SharePoint 2010 server environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is no such click event in InfoPath, only an Xml Changed event you can rig up to whatever element is storing the base64 string.